# Android Studio image not found

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utaqg.jpg)

I tried every possible way to solve this, but always gets no image:
1- uninstalled everything and install again.
2- changed the proxy to make it auto.
3- downloaded the files from android studio web site.
4- update and delete everything and un-install for a week and nothing changes.

so if anyone can help please..

Answer (score 0):

well, thanks to "Harshad Pansuriya" and "M. Bilal Asif"
I managed to remove android studio completely from my computer then installed a new fresh copy.
here is how to remove android studio from your pc (windows):
The first step is to run the uninstaller. Open the Control Panel and under Programs, select Uninstall a Program. After that, click on "Android Studio" and press Uninstall. If you have multiple versions, uninstall them as well.

Step 2: Remove the Android Studio files

To delete any remains of Android Studio setting files, in File Explorer, go to your user folder (%USERPROFILE%), and delete .android, .AndroidStudio and any analogous directories with versions on the end, i.e. .AndroidStudio1.2, as well as .gradle and .m2 if they exist.

Then go to %APPDATA% and delete the JetBrains directory.

Finally, go to C:\Program Files and delete the Android directory.

Step 3: Remove SDK

To delete any remains of the SDK, go to %LOCALAPPDATA% and delete the Android directory.

Step 4: Delete Android Studio projects

Android Studio creates projects in a folder %USERPROFILE%\AndroidStudioProjects, which you may want to delete.
5- Delete this Android Studio folder located at C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Local\Google

6- Delete this Android Studio folder located at C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Google.

Then install new fresh copy of android studio